# NUXT compress/minify/combine ccs, js and HTML

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, nuxt.js, yarnpkg

I am working on a project made using NUXT we use yarn for package management.

I need to compress (and perhaps combine if possible) js, css and html to speed up load time.

I read "https://www.npmjs.com/package/nuxt-compress"

I tried to add module.export to NUXT.config.js but couldn't make it to work.

Will some one kindly guide me step by step how to configure compression on build time as I am new to NUXT.

Where to put it and what command to run when I build or run the project.

I guess it is doing some thing similar to what I require when I do "yarn build". It is minifying the css and js. But can we do more? E.g. gzip and combine multiple js, css or html together?

Answer (score 0):

You can add to the build configuration of your Nuxt project using `html.minify`

This is the currently supported configuration: https://nuxtjs.org/api/configuration-build#html-minify

It uses https://github.com/kangax/html-minifier behind the scenes.

## html.minify

**Type:** Object

**Default:**

```
{
  collapseBooleanAttributes: true,
  decodeEntities: true,
  minifyCSS: true,
  minifyJS: true,
  processConditionalComments: true,
  removeEmptyAttributes: true,
  removeRedundantAttributes: true,
  trimCustomFragments: true,
  useShortDoctype: true
}
```

**Attention:** If you make changes to html.minify, they won't be merged with the defaults!

Configuration for the html-minifier plugin used to minify HTML files created during the build process (will be applied for all modes).

Answer (score 0):

This didn't work for me :(

```
npm install html-minifier
```

in nuxt.config.js

```
  build: {
    html: {
      minify:{
        collapseBooleanAttributes: true,
        decodeEntities: true,
        minifyCSS: true,
        minifyJS: true,
        processConditionalComments: true,
        removeEmptyAttributes: true,
        removeRedundantAttributes: true,
        trimCustomFragments: true,
        useShortDoctype: true,
        removeComments: true,
        preserveLineBreaks: false,
        collapseWhitespace: true
      }
    }, 
  },
```

Comment: by any chance u fix this ?

Comment: @AlanYong, It was working but not 100%, some HTML part were missing, I don't remember at this moment exactly the details, there was way to fix this problem but it required to add some ignore statements into the template files, it was not worth for me at that time so I gave up

Comment: @ArIT end up i gave up too. nuxtjs not mature after all. I switch to nextjs. much much much better

Comment: @AlanYong I am doing the same, I am starting learning React then Next